# Mirroring Azure VM data in realtime

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-virtual-machine

Currently I have only one VM deployed however I aim to have two deployed on the same availability set and have a load balancing between them.

My application in ASP can create extra HTML files.

If userA gets sent to SERVER A via the loadbalancing and the HTML page was created for their account on that server how would I make it available on SERVER B if they were directed to that VM at a later date via load balancing?

Comment: This question is really opinion-based, with no single right answer: Lots of ways to solve this (database, cache, CDN, Azure storage, etc.). How you actually do this is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Azure File Share seems the best bet.

Following a step by step guide over at: http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/09/23/step-by-step-create-a-file-share-in-azure.aspx